Is there anywhere I can change the color theme of the scifi.se site?
Recently (Last month or two?) on the SF&F SE the font of the tags changed to what appears to be bold black.
For me with my old eyes, their close proximity to the light blue font of the questions on the white background make them difficult to read. (Lots of eye strain trying not to see the black fonted tags, and read the question)
It would be nice if users could chose a color theme.
For me personally I would prefer the Questions were black font and the tags had the light blue font. (on the grey background of the tags I think the light blue would be more readable than it currently is for the light blue on white questions.)
Is there a setting in the preferences for use to chose a color theme? In  brief glance at the settings, I did not notice one.

Within the official site settings, no. You're stuck with the new stupid bold font that everyone hates and for some reason our SE masters have decided to inflict upon us.

Meta:SE - All tag labels suddenly appear in bold font

There are some off-site suggestions on ways to remove this monstrosity, using Stylus and a simple CSS command.




Thank You, added stylus and this takes care of my problem. MUCH more readable.

@NJohnny - You're very welcome
